# What does the fraction of correctly identified edges mean in community detection / clustering?

Tags: graph-theory, intuition, network, clustering

In some papers in community detection or network clustering, they use the following measure of quality for the detected communities (see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612, section XVB, 3rd paragraph)

> Fraction of correctly classified vertices. A vertex is correctly
>   classified if it is in the same cluster with at least half of its
>   “natural” partners. If the partition found by the algorithm has
>   clusters given by the merging of two or more natural groups, all
>   vertices of the cluster are considered incorrectly classified. The
>   number of correctly classified vertices is then divided by the total
>   size of the graph, to yield a number between 0 and 1.

I am very confused by this definition. Could someone explain how to compute this quantity given a ground truth partition $C = \{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ of the vertex set $V = \{1,\dots,v\}$ and another partition obtained from the community detection algorithm $D = \{d_1\dots d_m\}$?